# How to check whether an array is sorted or not using is_sorted function in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I need to check whether an array is sorted or not using the `std::is_sorted()` function. I am not sure how I would use `begin()` and `end()` so I just passed the array to the function.

```
void sorted(bool value){
    if(value)
        cout << "Array is sorted" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Array is not sorted" << endl;
}

int main(){
    int a[10], i;
    cout << "Enter the sequence" << endl;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    bool value = is_sorted(a);
    sorted(value);
    return 0;
}
```

When I do that though I get an error like

> there is no matching call for is_sorted function

Comment: Error stated that no matching call for is_sorted function.

Comment: `bool value = std::is_sorted(a, a + 5);` Don't forget to `#include <algorithm>`. Oh, and did you actually mean to declare an array with 10 elements, but then only fill 5 of them?

Comment: take a copy, sort the copy, compare copy with original -> set bool

Comment: The arguments you pass must be what [std::is_sorted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) expects, two iterators.

Comment: @FirstStep, and be as inefficient as possible?

Comment: Let me introduce you to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) beautiful site that answers questions like that a lot faster.

Comment: ehm.. @StoryTeller I didn't know it actually exist, but why my approach is not efficient?

Comment: @FirstStep - even if you had to implement this algorithm yourself, there's no reason to copy the vector. All you have to do is look at each pair of successive elements. If any of them are not in order, the vector is not sorted.

Comment: @FirstStep If this was an answer, I would downvote it. There already is (an  approach of) a better solution in the OP.

Comment: @BaummitAugen That's why I commented and not answered, I am trying to learn but also help and share knowledge and I really like it. And Ferruccio I see, check every successive elements, clever!

Comment: @Vishnu N K  As for me then I have not understood what is the question.

Comment: `is_sorted` checks for being sorted in ascending order by default (to be precise, sorted relative to `std::less` predicate). If you want to check for sorted descending, you can do `is_sorted(a, a+5, std::greater<int>())`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the fast response. It worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::is_sorted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) works on a range of iterators not on a "container".  To use it you need to pass an iterator to the start of the range you want to check and one past the end of the range you want to check.  Most if not all standard containers have a `begin()` and `end()` members which is very convenient but unfortunately a raw array does not.

Fortunately though we have [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) which will return an iterator and will work with raw arrays(this will not work if the array was passed to a function like `void foo(int arr[])` as it decays to a pointer and is not an array in the function).

So if you want to use `std::is_sorted` with a raw array you can use

```
std::is_sorted(std::begin(array_name), std::end(array_name));
```

Which will check the whole array.

Additionally you can also use pointer notation as that is what iterators are an abstraction of like

```
std::is_sorted(array_name + x, array_name + y)
```

Where `x` is in the range of `[0, array_size - 1]` and `y` is in the range of `[x + 1, array_size]`